# Sending Packet objects with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Take the following:

```
struct Header{
    std::size_t body_size;
};
struct Body{
    std::string data;
};
struct Packet{
    Header header;
    Body body;


};
```

Suppose now, that I want to send a `Packet` object over a  `tcp` socket.

To do this, I want to serialise the Header into a `std::string`, which contains information about how large the `body` is, and send that `string` over through the socket.

But this serialised header string itself has a variable size since the `body_size` is not fixed, so how would I know how many bytes to read (of the serialised header string)

So what kind of protocols are used in sending data like this?

Comment: For simple data you can serialize to JSON, or use a binary format like CBOR, or if you're up for a challenge, define your own data format with Google Protocol Buffers

Comment: Make your protocol in a way that every frame is of the form `[size data]`. First you read the size, and then you read the rest of the packet. This may not be the best way, but it is known to work in stream-oriented sockets.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to send the header as a string? TCP is a byte stream so you could send the `size_t` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used protocol for sending data over a `TCP` socket like you propose is [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230).
In `HTTP`, the body size is sent as a string in the relevant header [request, response or chunk] with special characters (`\r\n` for a request or response, `;` for a chunk) to identify the end of the size string.
You'll need to decide on your own special character; `NULL` would be the easiest for null terminated strings.

One of the key issues of sending data as you propose, is that `TCP` can split the data up into a number of (what are commonly called) `packets`, so the receiver may not receive the whole of your `Packet` at once.
BTW `Packet` is a poor name in this context.

You don't need to know the size of your complete `Packet` before you send it. You can call `boost:asio` [async_write](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html) with a collection of [const_buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/const_buffer.html)s to send both the `Header` and `Body` of your `Packet`.

On the receive side, I recommend using [async_read_some](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) with a `string` buffer large enough for your whole `Packet` including the `Header` string.
You should be able to read the `Body` size from the characters before the `NULL` and calculate your `Packet` size from the `Body` size plus the number of characters before the `NULL` + 1 (for the `NULL`). If this is less that the size reported by your [ReadHandler](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) then your `Body` has been split across multiple `TCP` `packets`, so you'll need to receive the other `packets` to reconstruct your `Packet` `Body`.

Or, you could save yourself the trouble and simply use a tried and tested `HTTP` library like [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib) or [boost::beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html).